# Spark context 'sc' not defined

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am new to Spark and I am trying to install the PySpark by referring to the below site.

http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/

I tried to install both prebuilt package and also by building the Spark package thru SBT.

When I try to run a python code in IPython Notebook I get the below error.

```
    NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-f7aa330f6984> in <module>()
      1 # Check that Spark is working
----> 2 largeRange = sc.parallelize(xrange(100000))
      3 reduceTest = largeRange.reduce(lambda a, b: a + b)
      4 filterReduceTest = largeRange.filter(lambda x: x % 7 == 0).sum()
      5 

      NameError: name 'sc' is not defined
```

In the command window I can see the below error.

```
<strong>Failed to find Spark assembly JAR.</strong>
<strong>You need to build Spark before running this program.</strong>
```

Note that I got a scala prompt when I executed *spark-shell* command

**Update:**

With help of a friend I am able to fix the issue related to Spark assembly JAR by correcting the contents of .ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py file

I have now only the problem of Spark Context variable. Changing the title to be appropriately reflect my current issue.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

One solution is adding `pyspark-shell` to the shell environment variable PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS:

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
```

There is a change in  [python/pyspark/java_gateway.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/commit/e3f315ac358dfe4f5b9705c3eac76e8b1e24f82a#diff-d88dad45f458b7ad9f1c6a63b07e3a28) , which requires PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS includes `pyspark-shell` if a PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS variable is set by a user.

Comment: Is this change in spark 1.4? May be that's the reason 1.4 gives me error when I launch but 1.3.1 does not

Comment: yes since 1.4.x. I would like to add comments.

In fact, `$SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark` has an official way to launch ipython or ipython notebook. For 1.4.x,

Comment: You could launch ipython or ipython notebook using $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark, check that bash script.

    PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark
    PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook' $SPARK_HOME/bin/pyspark

Comment: IMHO this is the best solution.

Answer (score 54):

you need to do the following after you have pyspark in your path:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
```

Comment: Thanks Venu. When I add those lines I am getting the below error. C:\Spark\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\java_gateway.pyc in launch_gateway()
     77                 callback_socket.close()
     78         if gateway_port is None:
---> 79             raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
     80 
     81         # In Windows, ensure the Java child processes do not linger after Python has exited.

Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Comment: Not sure what is going on there, can you give me a bit more context

Comment: perfect, but I think you can make your code looks better by adding some ardents

Answer (score 14):

You have to creat instance of SparkContext like following:

import:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
```

and then:

```
sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()
```

*NB:`sc =SparkContext.getOrCreate()` works well than `sc =SparkContext()`.*

Comment: `SparkContext.getOrCreate()` was needed to resolve the issue, I had.

Answer (score 5):

Just a little improvement. Add following at top of your python script file.

```
#! /bin/python
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
sc =SparkContext()

# your code starts here
```

Answer (score 4):

This worked for me in the spark version 2.3.1

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
```

Answer (score 2):

I added the below lines provided by Venu.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc =SparkContext()
```

Then the below subsequent error was resolved by removing the Environment variable PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS.

```
C:\Spark\spark-1.3.1-bin-hadoop2.6\python\pyspark\java_gateway.pyc in launch_gateway() 77 callback_socket.close() 78 if gateway_port is None: 
---> 79 raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number") 
80 
81 # In Windows, ensure the Java child processes do not linger after Python has exited. Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

Answer (score 2):

I also encountered the `Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number` error message.

I could solve that problem by downloading one of the versions that are prebuilt for Hadoop (I used the one for hadoop 2.4). As I do not use Hadoop, I have no idea why this changed something, but it now works flawlessly for me...

Answer (score 2):

I was getting a similar error trying to get pySpark working via PyCharm, and I noticed in the log, just before this error I was getting this error:

env: not found

I traced this down to the fact that I did not have a Java home environment variable set.. so I added 
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = "/usr/java/jdk1.7.0_67-cloudera"

to my script ( I am aware that this is probably not the best place for it) 
and the error goes and I get my spark object created

Answer (score 1):

Spark on my Mac is 1.6.0 so adding `pyspark-shell` did not solve the problem. 
What worked for me is following the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31193768/error-must-specify-a-primary-resource-jar-or-python-or-r-file-ipython-noteb/) by @karenyng

```
pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
if not "pyspark-shell" in pyspark_submit_args: pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
```

Answer (score 1):

While working on IBM Watson Studio Jupyter notebook I faced a similar issue, I solved it by the following methods,

```
!pip install pyspark
from pyspark import SparkContext
sc = SparkContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem in my case problem was another notebook was running (in recent versions they are shown in green). I selected and shut down one of them and it worked fine.

Sorry for invoking old thread but it may help someone :)

Answer (score 0):

This script worked for me (in linux):

```
#!/bin/bash

export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython
export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS="--pylab -c 'from pyspark import SparkContext; sc=SparkContext()' -i"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"

pyspark
```

To call `pyspark` as I'm calling there I'm assuming that "spark/bin" installation path is in the `PATH` variable. If not, call instead `/path/to/spark/bin/pyspark`.

Answer (score 0):

To the Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

You need install Java8 in your computer.