# Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file) - IPython notebook

Tags: apache-spark, ipython, pyspark

I try to run Apache Spark in IPython Notebook, follow this insruction (and all advice in comments) - [link](http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/)

But when I run IPython Notebook by this command:

```
ipython notebook --profile=pyspark
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Must specify a primary resource (JAR or Python or R file)
```

If i run pyspark in shell, everything OK. That means what I have some trouble with connection Spark and IPython.

By the way, this my bash_profile:

```
export SPARK_HOME="$HOME/spark-1.4.0"
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS='--conf "spark.mesos.coarse=true" pyspark-shell'
```

And this contain **~/.ipython/profile_pyspark/startup/00-pyspark-setup.py**:

```
# Configure the necessary Spark environment
import os
import sys

# Spark home
spark_home = os.environ.get("SPARK_HOME")

# If Spark V1.4.x is detected, then add ' pyspark-shell' to
# the end of the 'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS' environment variable
spark_release_file = spark_home + "/RELEASE"
if os.path.exists(spark_release_file) and "Spark 1.4" in  open(spark_release_file).read():
    pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
    if not "pyspark-shell" in pyspark_submit_args: pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
    os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args

# Add the spark python sub-directory to the path
sys.path.insert(0, spark_home + "/python")

# Add the py4j to the path.
# You may need to change the version number to match your install
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.join(spark_home, "python/lib/py4j-0.8.2.1-src.zip"))

# Initialize PySpark to predefine the SparkContext variable 'sc'
execfile(os.path.join(spark_home, "python/pyspark/shell.py"))
```

And what may be neccesary - yesterday I upgraded my OS X to 10.10.4

Comment: I would try things like https://pypi.python.org/pypi/findspark to setup spark, instead of relying on blog post that tell you to configure things in a complex way that is not necessary and less flexible.

Comment: So, I try, but it is doesn't help. Anyway, thank you!

Comment: @Matt I wish I could give your comment 5 upvotes. I've tried many of the blogposts, and the new Toree project, with varying degrees of pain and not much success. With findspark, again MinRK comes with a great solution that is simple to use.

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem and I used the same `00-pyspark-setup.py` file when used with `spark-1.4.0`.

As explained by the comments of Philippe Rossignol on [this blog](http://ramhiser.com/2015/02/01/configuring-ipython-notebook-support-for-pyspark/),
the following lines were added to the `00-pyspark-setup.py` file 
since the argument `pyspark-shell` is needed for `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`:

```
# If Spark V1.4.x is detected, then add ' pyspark-shell' to
# the end of the 'PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS' environment variable
spark_release_file = spark_home + "/RELEASE"
if os.path.exists(spark_release_file) and "Spark 1.4" in open(spark_release_file).read():
    pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
    if not "pyspark-shell" in pyspark_submit_args: pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
    os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
```

However inside my `spark-1.4.0` folder, there was no `RELEASE` file, so the `if` condition to append `pyspark-shell` to `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` was never satisfied.

As a kludgy solution I just commented out the lines checking the release file so only the following lines are left:

```
pyspark_submit_args = os.environ.get("PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS", "")
if not "pyspark-shell" in pyspark_submit_args: pyspark_submit_args += " pyspark-shell"
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = pyspark_submit_args
```