# Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number

Tags: java, python, macos, apache-spark, pyspark

I'm trying to run pyspark on my macbook air. When i try starting it up I get the error:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

when sc = SparkContext() is being called upon startup. I have tried running the following commands:

```
./bin/pyspark
./bin/spark-shell
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
```

with no avail. I have also looked here:

[Spark + Python - Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31825911/spark-python-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-port)

but the question has never been answered. Please help! Thanks.

Comment: I resolved the above problem by downloading a different tarbll of spark.

Comment: See my comments at-
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po/32347328#32347328

Comment: In addition to @mt88's comment, spark-1.6.0-bin-without-hadoop.tgz produces the above exception, but spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6.tgz doesn't for me on Ubuntu 15.04

Comment: @zyxue I'm also using Spark 2.2.1 without Hadoop. Do you think that's the cause?

Comment: @lfk, not sure of your question, you could just try and see

Comment: @zyxue I'll have to build Spark in that case as the pre built version comes with 2.7 and I need 3

Comment: @lfk, `Spark runs on Java 8+, Python 2.7+/3.4+ and R 3.1+. For the Scala API, Spark 2.2.1 uses Scala 2.11. You will need to use a compatible Scala version (2.11.x).`, https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/, so python 3 shouldn't be a problem. If you're working on a single node, then building it yourself is ok, but still I would recommend you to install it with some sort of a package manager, e.g. anaconda. The latest version pyspark, https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyspark/2.1.1, it supports python3.

Comment: @zyxue I'm sorry I meant Hadoop 3. That's why I'm using the Hadoop-free binaries. pip pyspark is prebuilt with Hadoop 2.7.

Answer (score 47):

One possible reason is JAVA_HOME is not set because java is not installed.

I encountered the same issue. It says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/apache/spark/launcher/Main : Unsupported major.minor version 51.0
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:643)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:277)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:73)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:212)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:205)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:323)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:296)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:268)
    at sun.launcher.LauncherHelper.checkAndLoadMain(LauncherHelper.java:406)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/conf.py", line 104, in __init__
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/context.py", line 243, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
  File "/opt/spark/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

at `sc = pyspark.SparkConf()`. I solved it by running

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

which is from https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-ubuntu-16-04

Comment: For a fully automatic installation of Oracle Java8 on Ubuntu see https://newfivefour.com/docker-java8-auto-install.html .

Comment: I'm confused.  How can you not have java installed with an error like that?  The first part of it is a java stack trace!  I think you simply had the problem that JAVA_HOME wasn't set correctly/at all.

Answer (score 35):

this should help you

One solution is adding pyspark-shell to the shell environment variable PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS:

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
```

There is a change in python/pyspark/java_gateway.py , which requires PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS includes pyspark-shell if a PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS variable is set by a user.

Comment: Do you have any pointer to such "change in python/pyspark/java_gateway.py", which version, line, etc.?

Answer (score 30):

Had this error message running pyspark on Ubuntu, got rid of it by installing the `openjdk-8-jdk` package

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
sc = SparkContext(conf=SparkConf().setAppName("MyApp").setMaster("local"))
^^^ error
```

Install Open JDK 8:

```
apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq
```

#### On MacOS

Same on Mac OS, I typed in a terminal:

```
$ java -version
No Java runtime present, requesting install.
```

I was prompted to install Java from the [Oracle's download site](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk13-downloads.html), chose the MacOS installer, clicked on `jdk-13.0.2_osx-x64_bin.dmg` and after that checked that Java was installed

```
$ java -version
java version "13.0.2" 2020-01-14
```

EDIT To install JDK 8 you need to go to https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase-jdk8-downloads.html (login required)

After that I was able to start a Spark context with pyspark.

#### Checking if it works

In Python:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext 
sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate() 

# check that it really works by running a job
# example from http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/rdd-programming-guide.html#parallelized-collections
data = range(10000) 
distData = sc.parallelize(data)
distData.filter(lambda x: not x&1).take(10)
# Out: [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18]
```

Note that you might need to set the environment variables `PYSPARK_PYTHON` and `PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON` and they have to be the same Python version as the Python (or IPython) you're using to run pyspark (the driver).

Answer (score 12):

I use Mac OS. I fixed the problem!

Below is how I fixed it.

JDK8 seems works fine. (https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/248)

So I checked my JDK **/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines**, I only have **jdk-11.jdk** in this path.

I [downloaded JDK8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac) (I followed the link).
Which is:

```
brew tap caskroom/versions
brew cask install java8
```

After this, I added

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_202.jdk/Contents/Home
export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"
```

to **~/.bash_profile** file.  (you sholud check your jdk1.8 file name)

It works now!
Hope this help :)

Comment: To clarify, the fix here is `export JAVA_HOME="$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)"` and there is an extended discussion on Github https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/248#issuecomment-926782387. Yes, the link is to Jupyter, but it's regarding an issue with PySpark. Adding the first assignment to JAVA_HOME does nothing.

Answer (score 10):

I will repost [how I solved it](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743) here just for future references.

**How I solved my similar problem**

*Prerequisite:*

1. anaconda already installed
2. Spark already installed (https://spark.apache.org/downloads.html)
3. pyspark already installed (https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/pyspark)

*Steps I did* (NOTE: set the folder path accordingly to your system)

> 1. set the following environment variables.
> 2. SPARK_HOME to 'C:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7'
> 3. set HADOOP_HOME  to 'C:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7'
> 4. set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON to 'jupyter'
> 5. set PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS to 'notebook'
> 6. add 'C:\spark\spark-3.0.1-bin-hadoop2.7\bin;' to PATH system variable.
> 7. Change the java installed folder directly under C: (Previously java was installed under Program files, so I re-installed directly
>    under C:)
> 8. so my JAVA_HOME will become like this 'C:\java\jdk1.8.0_271'

now. it works !

Answer (score 9):

I had the same error with PySpark, and setting JAVA_HOME to Java 11 worked for me (it was originally set to 16). I'm using MacOS and PyCharm.
You can check your current Java version by doing `echo $JAVA_HOME`.

Below is what worked for me. On my Mac I used the following homebrew command, but you can use a different method to install the desired Java version, depending on your OS.

```
# Install Java 11 (I believe 8 works too)
$ brew install openjdk@11

# Set JAVA_HOME by assigning the path where your Java is
$ export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11
```

Note: If you installed using homebrew and need to find the location of the path, you can do `$ brew --prefix openjdk@11` and it should return a path like this: `/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11`

At this point, I could run my PySpark program from the terminal - however, my IDE (PyCharm) still had the same error until I globally changed the JAVA_HOME variable.

To update the variable, first check whether you're using the zsh or bash shell by running `echo $SHELL` on the command line. For zsh, you'll edit the `~/.zshenv` file and for bash you'll edit the `~/.bash_profile`.

```
# open the file
$ vim ~/.zshenv
OR
$ vim ~/.bash_profile

# once inside the file, set the variable with your Java path, then save and close the file
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11

# test if it was set successfully
$ echo $JAVA_HOME
/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11
```

After this step, I could run PySpark through my PyCharm IDE as well.

Comment: I have mine at `/usr/local/opt/openjdk@8` and something seems to be wrong with this &  `pytest-spark`. It says it cant find the Java installation

`Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again`...

`RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number`

Answer (score 7):

Had the same issue with my iphython notebook (IPython 3.2.1) on Linux (ubuntu).

What was missing in my case was setting the master URL in the $PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS environment like this (assuming you use bash):

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master spark://<host>:<port>"
```

e.g.

```
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master spark://192.168.2.40:7077"
```

You can put this into your .bashrc file. You get the correct URL in the log for the spark master (the location for this log is reported when you start the master with /sbin/start_master.sh).

Comment: Since I can't comment on user1613333 answer I do it here, I also found that using Anaconda makes things go much smoother.

Comment: You can also set environment variables using `import os; os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = "--master ..."`

Comment: @quax I used 'os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS']= "--master spark://localhost:8888" ' but I do not know if I am doing wrong, still no works

Comment: What bash file where and why? WTH is `/sbin/` (I'm on Windows)? @BallpointBen appreciate the addition, but same error as before.

Answer (score 7):

After spending hours and hours trying many different solutions, I can confirm that Java 10 SDK causes this error. On Mac, please navigate to /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines then run this command to uninstall Java JDK 10 completely:

```
sudo rm -rf jdk-10.jdk/
```

After that, please download JDK 8 then the problem will be solved.

Answer (score 6):

There are many valuable hints here, however, none solved my problem completely so I will show the procedure that worked for me working in an **Anaconda Jupyter Notebook** on **Windows**:

- Download and install java and pyspark in directories without blank spaces.
- [maybe unnecessary] In the anaconda prompt, type `where conda` and `where python` and add the paths of the .exe files' directories to your Path variable using the Windows environmental variables tool. Add also the variables `JAVA_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` there with their corresponding paths.
- Even doing so, I had to set these variables manually from within the Notebook along with `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` (use your own paths for `SPARK_HOME` and `JAVA_HOME`):

`import os`
`os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = r"C:\Spark\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2"`
`os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--master local[3] pyspark-shell"`
`os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = r"C:\Java\jre1.8.0_311"`

- Install findspark from the notebook with `!pip install findspark`.
- Run `import findspark` and `findspark.init()`
- Run `from pyspark.sql import SparkSession` and `spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()`

Some useful links:

https://towardsdatascience.com/installing-apache-pyspark-on-windows-10-f5f0c506bea1

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-port-number/

https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/installing-anaconda-windows

Comment: "in directories without blank spaces" - life saving comment. Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

Spark is very picky with the Java version you use. It is highly recommended that you use Java 1.8 (The open source AdoptOpenJDK 8 works well too).
After install it, set `JAVA_HOME` to your bash variables, if you use Mac/Linux:

`export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)`

`export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH`

Answer (score 4):

I got the same `Java gateway process exited......port number` exception even though I set `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` properly. I'm running Spark 1.6 and trying to get pyspark to work with IPython4/Jupyter (OS: ubuntu as VM guest).

While I got this exception, I noticed an hs_err_*.log was generated and it started with:

`There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue. Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 715849728 bytes for committing reserved memory.`

So I increased the memory allocated for my ubuntu via VirtualBox Setting and restarted the guest ubuntu. Then this `Java gateway` exception goes away and everything worked out fine.

Comment: Where do I find that log file?

Comment: boom, great answer

Answer (score 3):

I got the same `Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number` in Cloudera VM when trying to start IPython with CSV support with a syntax error:

`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10.1.4.0`

will throw the error, while:

`PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=ipython pyspark --packages com.databricks:spark-csv_2.10:1.4.0`

will not.

The difference is in that last **colon** in the last (working) example, seperating the **Scala version number** from the **package version number**.

Answer (score 3):

If you are trying to run spark without hadoop binaries, you might encounter the above mentioned error. One solution is to :

1) download hadoop separatedly.
2) add hadoop to your PATH
3) add hadoop classpath to your SPARK install

The first two steps are trivial, the last step can be best done by adding the following in the $SPARK_HOME/conf/spark-env.sh in each spark node (master and workers)

```sh
### in conf/spark-env.sh ###

export SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH=$(hadoop classpath)
```

for more info also check: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/hadoop-provided.html

Answer (score 3):

I was getting this error when i was using jdk-1.8 32-bit
switching to 64-bit works for me.

I was getting this error because 32-bit java could not allocate more than 3G heap memory required by the spark driver (16G):

```
builder = SparkSession.builder \
        .appName("Spark NLP") \
        .master("local[*]") \
        .config("spark.driver.memory", "16G") \
        .config("spark.serializer", "org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer") \
        .config("spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max", "1000M") \
        .config("spark.driver.maxResultSize", "0")
```

I tested making this up to 2G and it worked in 32-bit as well.

Answer (score 3):

After spending a good amount of time with this issue, I was able to solve this. I own MacOs Catalina, working on Pycharm in an Anaconda environment.

Spark currently supports only Java8. If you install Java through command line, it will by default install the latest Java10+ and would cause all sorts of troubles. To solve this, follow the below steps -

```
1. Make sure you have Homebrew, else install Homebrew
/usr/bin/ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/master/install)"

2. Install X-code
xcode-select –-install

3. Install Java8 through the official website (not through terminal)
https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/javase-jdk8-downloads.html

4. Install Apache-Spark
 brew install apache-spark 

5. Install Pyspark and Findspark (if you have anaconda)
conda install -c conda-forge findspark 
conda install -c conda-forge/label/gcc7 findspark
conda install -c conda-forge pyspark
```

**Viola!** this should let you run PySpark without any issues

Comment: Great answer! it worked for me on MacOS Monterey (12.4)

Answer (score 2):

I got this error because I was running low on disk space.

Answer (score 2):

In my case this error came for the script which was running fine before. So I figured out that this might be due to my JAVA update. Before I was using java 1.8 but I had accidentally updated to java 1.9. When I switched back to java 1.8 the error disappeared and everything is running fine. 
For those, who get this error for the same reason but do not know how to switch back to older java version on ubuntu: 
run

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

and make the selection for java version

Comment: Thx - this solved my problem on KDE Neon (based on Ubuntu 16.04).

Answer (score 2):

I figured out the problem in Windows system. The installation directory for Java must not have blanks in the path such as in `C:\Program Files`. I re-installed Java in `C\Java`. I set `JAVA_HOME` to `C:\Java` and the problem went away.

Answer (score 2):

For Linux (Ubuntu 18.04) with a JAVA_HOME issue, a key is to point it to the **master** folder:

1. Set Java 8 as default by: **`sudo update-alternatives --config java`**. If Jave 8 is not installed, install by: **`sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`**.
2. Set `JAVA_HOME` environment variable as the **master** java 8 folder. The location is given by the first command above removing `jre/bin/java`. Namely: **`export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/"`**. If done on the command line, this will be relevant only for the current session ([ref: export command on Linux](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_commands/export.htm)). To verify: **`echo $JAVA_HOME`**.
3. In order to have this permanently set, add the bolded line above to a file that runs before you start your IDE/Jupyter/python interpreter. This could be by adding the bolded line above to **`.bashrc`**. This file loads when a bash is started interactively [ref: .bashrc](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/129143/what-is-the-purpose-of-bashrc-and-how-does-it-work)

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me, I'm using Fedora. It's the JAVA path that has to be set to /usr/lib/jvm/java-(whatever JDK verison). This took time to figure out, thank you again

Answer (score 1):

Had same issue, after installing java using below lines solved the issue !

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error.

My trouble shooting procedures are:

1. Check out Spark source code.
2. Follow the error message. In my case: `pyspark/java_gateway.py`, line 93, in `launch_gateway`.
3. Check the code logic to find the root cause then you will resolve it.

In my case the issue is PySpark has no permission to create some temporary directory, so I just run my IDE with sudo

Answer (score 1):

I have the same error in running pyspark in pycharm.
I solved the problem by adding JAVA_HOME in pycharm's environment variables.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was because I wrote `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=10` instead of `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=10g` in `spark-env.sh`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exception and I tried everything by setting and resetting all environment variables. But the issue in the end drilled down to space in appname property of spark session,that is, "SparkSession.builder.appName("StreamingDemo").getOrCreate()". Immediately after removing space from string given to appname property it got resolved.I was using pyspark 2.7 with eclipse on windows 10 environment. It worked for me.
Enclosed are required screenshots.[image: Error_with space]

[image: No Error_without space]

Answer (score 1):

The error occured since JAVA is not installed on machine.
Spark is developed in scala which usually runs on JAVA.

Try to install JAVA and execute the pyspark statements.
It will works

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens if you do not have java installed in your machine.

Go to command prompt and check the version of your java: 
type : `java -version`

you should get output sth like this

`java version "1.8.0_241"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_241-b07)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.241-b07, mixed mode)`

If not, go to orcale and download jdk. 
Check this video on how to download java and add it to the buildpath.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f7rT0h1Q5Wo

Answer (score 1):

**Step:1**

Check the java vesrion on from the terminal.

```
java -version
```

If you see the `bash: java: command not found`,which mean you don't have java installed in your system.

**Step:2**

Install Java using the following command,

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

**Step:3**

No check java version, you'll see the version have been downloaded.

```
java -version
```

result:

```
openjdk version "11.0.11" 2021-04-20
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.11+9-Ubuntu-0ubuntu2.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**Step:4**

Now run the pyspark code,
you'll never see such error.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem and actually not due to the JAVE_HOME setting. i assume you are using windows, and using Anaconda as your python tools. Please check whether you can use command prompt. I cannot run spark due to the crash of cmd. After fix this, spark can work well on my pc.

Comment: [how to fix your cmd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66335300/cmd-crashes-with-exit-code-1-after-uninstalling-anaconda)

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30695717)

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same problem, tried many different things but the solution that worked for me was to simply install java 8 (and uninstall any other version of java if any on your machine.)

**Step 1**: install java 8
[Download java 8 here](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/downloads/#java8-windows)

note: download x64 Installer for windows
[image]
**Step 2**: set JAVA_HOME environment variable.

for example,

```
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_351
```

That's all. With these 2 simple steps, I was able to fix the problem.

Comment: Be aware Java 8 is not getting all the security updates, only critical patches. Medium-term you want to migrate to Java 11.

Answer (score 1):

This error indicates there is a **mismatch between PySpark and Java version**. Both of them are not compatible. **See the below compatibility matrix.**

```
PySpark Version  Min Java Version
-------------------------------------
2.0.x - 2.2.x    Java 7
2.3.x - 2.4.x    Java 8
3.0.x - 3.1.x    Java 8
3.2.x            Java 11
```

Check your JAVA version
**If it is 17, then you need PySpark 3.3 at least.
So upgrade the PySpark**.

Answer (score 0):

Worked hours on this. My problem was with Java 10 installation. I uninstalled it and installed Java 8, and now Pyspark works.

Comment: but if you type java -version showed another version instead 8?

Answer (score 0):

For me, the answer was to add two 'Content Roots' in 'File' -> 'Project Structure' -> 'Modules' (in IntelliJ):

1. YourPath\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python
2. YourPath\spark-2.2.1-bin-hadoop2.7\python\lib\py4j-0.10.4-src.zip

Answer (score 0):

This is an old thread but I'm adding my solution for those who use mac.

The issue was with the `JAVA_HOME`.  You have to include this in your `.bash_profile`.

Check your `java -version`. If you downloaded the latest Java but it doesn't show up as the latest version, then you know that the path is wrong.  Normally, the default path is `export JAVA_HOME= /usr/bin/java`.

So try changing the path to:
`/Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home/bin/java`

Alternatively you could also download the latest JDK.
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html and this will automatically replace `usr/bin/java` to the latest version.  You can confirm this by doing `java -version` again.

Then that should work.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both your Java directory (as found in your path) AND your Python interpreter reside in directories with no spaces in them. These were the cause of my problem.

Answer (score 0):

There are so many reasons for this error. My reason is : the version of pyspark is incompatible with spark. 
pyspark version :2.4.0, but spark version is 2.2.0.
it always cause python always fail when starting spark process. then spark cannot tell its ports to python. so error will be "Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
".

I suggest you dive into source code to find out the real reasons when this error happens

Answer (score 0):

I go this error fixed by using the below code. I had setup the SPARK_HOME though. You may follow this simple steps from [eproblems website](https://eproblems.wordpress.com/2019/07/14/how-to-start-with-pyspark-on-windows-10/)

```
spark_home = os.environ.get('SPARK_HOME', None)
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue when was trying to run the pyspark job triggered from the Airflow with remote spark.driver.host. The cause of the issue in my case was:

> Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its
>   port number

...

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Exception: When running with master 'yarn' either HADOOP_CONF_DIR or YARN_CONF_DIR must be set in the environment.

Fixed by adding exports:

```
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR=/etc/hadoop/conf
```

And the same environment variable added in the pyspark script:

```
import os
os.environ["HADOOP_CONF_DIR"] = '/etc/hadoop/conf'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue once when I brought up Spark using Docker container. It turned out I set wrong permission for the **/tmp** folder.
If spark has no write permission on **/tmp**, it will cause this issue too.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply run the following code in the terminal. Then, I hope this will resolve your error.

```
sudo apt-get install default-jdk
```

Answer (score 0):

The error usually occurs when your system doesn't have java installed.

Check if you have java installed, open up the terminal and do
`java --version`

It's always advisable to use brew install for installing packages.
`brew install openjdk@11` for installing java

Now that you have java installed, set the path globally depending on the shell you use: Z shell or bash.

1. cmd + shift + H: Go to home
2. cmd + shift + [.]: To see the hidden files (zshenv or bash_profile) and save either of the file under `export JAVA_HOME=/usr/local/opt/openjdk@11`

Comment: I have java installed. JAVA_HOME also set yet the same issue

Answer (score 0):

## Background

The error `Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number` occurs in [SPARK_HOME/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/java_gateway.py](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/python/pyspark/java_gateway.py).

```
            if not on_windows:
                # Don't send ctrl-c / SIGINT to the Java gateway:
                def preexec_func():
                    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)

                popen_kwargs["preexec_fn"] = preexec_func
                proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)
            else:
                # preexec_fn not supported on Windows
                proc = Popen(command, **popen_kwargs)

            # Wait for the file to appear, or for the process to exit, whichever happens first.
            while not proc.poll() and not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
                time.sleep(0.1)

            if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
                raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")      # <-----
```

The code simulates this pyspark process invocation to test if the PySpark has been started.

## Test

Run the code below to make sure pyspark is invoked. This is specific to Spark installed with homebrew on Mac Apple Silicon but the idea and approach will be applicable to other platforms. The Spark version is 3.3.1. Need to change the versions accordingly.

```
import os
import shutil
import signal
import sys
import tempfile
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Constant
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
SPARK_HOME = "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec"
JAVA_HOME = '/opt/homebrew/opt/openjdk'

# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Environment Variables
# NOTE:
# SPARK_HOME must be set to /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec",
# NOT /opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1".
# Otherwise Java gateway process exited before sending its port number in java_gateway.py
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
os.environ['SPARK_HOME'] = SPARK_HOME
os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = JAVA_HOME
sys.path.extend([
    f"{SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/py4j-0.10.9.5-src.zip",
    f"{SPARK_HOME}/python/lib/pyspark.zip",
])


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# Pyspark Modules
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
from pyspark.serializers import read_int, UTF8Deserializer


# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# --------------------------------------------------------------------------------
def preexec_func():
    signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, signal.SIG_IGN)


def run_pyspark():
    """
    """
    pyspark_command = [f'{SPARK_HOME}/bin/spark-submit', '--master', 'local[*]', 'pyspark-shell']

    # Create a temporary directory where the gateway server should write the connection
    # information.
    proc = None
    conn_info_dir = tempfile.mkdtemp()
    try:
        fd, conn_info_file = tempfile.mkstemp(dir=conn_info_dir)
        os.close(fd)
        os.unlink(conn_info_file)

        env = dict(os.environ)
        env["_PYSPARK_DRIVER_CONN_INFO_PATH"] = conn_info_file

        # Launch the Java gateway.
        popen_kwargs = {"stdin": PIPE, "env": env}
        # We open a pipe to stdin so that the Java gateway can die when the pipe is broken
        # We always set the necessary environment variables.

        print(f"\nrun pyspark command line {pyspark_command}")
        popen_kwargs["preexec_fn"] = preexec_func
        proc = Popen(pyspark_command, **popen_kwargs)

        # Wait for the file to appear, or for the process to exit, whichever happens first.
        count: int = 5
        while not proc.poll() and not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
            print("waiting for pyspark to start...")
            count -= 1
            if count < 0:
                break

            time.sleep(1)

        if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
            raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")

        with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:
            gateway_port = read_int(info)
            gateway_secret = UTF8Deserializer().loads(info)

        out, err = proc.communicate()
        print("-"*80)
        print(f"pyspark started with pid {proc.pid}")
        print(f"spark process port {gateway_port}")
    finally:
        shutil.rmtree(conn_info_dir)
        if proc:
            proc.kill()


def test():
    run_pyspark()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    test()
```

## Environment

```
Mac OS Ventua 13.0.1
Python 3.9.13
PySpark 3.3.1
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (AdoptOpenJDK)(build 1.8.0_292-b10)
Scala code runner version 3.2.2
```

JDK 8, Scala, Spark have been installed with brew.

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk8
brew install scala
brew install apache-spark
```

Java process is allowed to get incoming connections at System Preferences > Security > Firewall.

[image]

## References

- [PySpark Installation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html#manually-downloading)

> Ensure the SPARK_HOME environment variable points to the directory where the tar file has been extracted.
> Update PYTHONPATH environment variable such that it can find the PySpark and Py4J under SPARK_HOME/python/lib. One example of doing this is shown below:

Answer (score -5):

If you are using Jupyter notebook from the window machine.

just use the following code

```
spark =SparkSession.builder.appName('myapp').getOrCreate
```

**Don't use like**

```
spark =SparkSession.builder.appName('myapp').getOrCreate()
```