# PySpark java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException

Tags: ubuntu, apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, apache-spark-sql

I followed [these instructions](https://sigdelta.com/blog/how-to-install-pyspark-locally/) and installed Apache Spark (PySpark) 2.3.1 on my machine which has the specifications:

- Ubuntu 18.04
- JDK 10
- Python 3.6

When I create a [`SparkSession`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/preview/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.SparkSession) either indirectly by calling `pyspark` from the shell or by directly creating a session in my app with:

```py
spark = pyspark.sql.SparkSession.builder.appName('test').getOrCreate()
```

I get the following exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.StringUtils.<clinit>(StringUtils.java:80)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.SecurityUtil.getAuthenticationMethod(SecurityUtil.java:611)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.initialize(UserGroupInformation.java:273)
....
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:137)
    at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: begin 0, end 3, length 2
    at java.base/java.lang.String.checkBoundsBeginEnd(String.java:3107)
    at java.base/java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1873)
    at org.apache.hadoop.util.Shell.<clinit>(Shell.java:52)
    ... 22 more
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 38, in <module>
    SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/context.py", line 292, in _ensure_initialized
    SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
  File "/home/welshamy/tools/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pyspark/java_gateway.py", line 93, in launch_gateway
    raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

If I'm using a Jupyter notebook, I also get this exception in the notebook:

```
Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

All the solutions I found and followed [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po),[2](https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/743),[3](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/248)] point toward environment variables definitions, but non of them worked for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PySpark 2.3.1 does not support JDK 10+.  You need to **install JDK 8** and **set the `JAVA_HOME`** environment variable to point to it.

If you are using Ubuntu (or *nix):

1. Install JDK 8

   ```
   sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk
   ```
2. Add the following line to your `~/.bashrc` file:

   ```
   export JAVA_HOME="/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64"
   ```

Under Windows, [install JDK 8](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/install/install_overview.html#A1096936) and [set `JAVA_HOME`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/820-7851/inst_cli_jdk_javahome_t/).

Answer (score 0):

For macOS, I had to

- Install Java 8, eg

```
brew install --cask adoptopenjdk/openjdk/adoptopenjdk8
```

- add $JAVA_HOME to my ~/.zshrc

```
export JAVA_HOME='/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/adoptopenjdk-8.jdk/Contents/Home'
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home -v 1.8)
```

- remove any other jdk installs

```
ls /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines
sudo rm -rf NONJDK8.jdk
```

The 3rd bit is important! It did not work until I removed other-versioned jdks.