# How to fix 'Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number' in Eclipse IDE

Tags: pyspark

I am trying to connect MySQL using pyspark in pydev environment of Eclipse IDE.
Getting below error:

Exception: **Java gateway process exited before sending its port number**

I have checked Java is properly installed and also set `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS` to value `--master local[*] --jars path\mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar pyspark-shell` in windows-> preferences->Pydev->Python Interpreter->Environment.

Java Path is also set. Tried setting it via code also but no luck.

```
#import os
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

from pyspark.sql.context import SQLContext

#os.environ['JAVA_HOME']= 'C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_141/'

#os.environ['PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS'] = '--jars D:/Softwares/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.tar/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44/mysql-connector-java-5.1.44-bin.jar pyspark-shell'

conf = SparkConf().setMaster('local').setAppName('MySQLdataread')

sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

dataframe_mysql = sqlContext.read.format("jdbc").option("url", "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/").option("driver", "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").option("dbtable", "XXXXX").option("user", "root").option("password", "XXXX").load()

dataframe_mysql.show()
```

Comment: Nitpick: It's spelled Java and not JAVA. It is not an acronym.

Comment: Thanks corrected ! can you please help me with the solution too

Comment: You may look into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35080073/3640307) and see what your error log file says.

Comment: @SajibAcharya I am not running any VM eclipse is installed in my OS only and also MySQL Local host. So memory problem i guess wont be the reason. I have tried all the possible solution given in that post still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was slightly different, I am running spark in spyder with windows.
when I am using

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext, SparkSession
```

I had the issue and followed google search links and not able to solve the problem.

Then I changed the import to:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import  SQLContext
```

and the error message disappeared.

I am running on Windows, anaconda3, python3.7, spyder  Hope it is helpful to someone.

**Edit:**
Later, i found the real problem is from the following.  When any of the configuration was not working properly, the same exception shows up.  Previously, I used 28gb and 4gb instead of 28g and 4g and that cause all the problems I had.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark import  SQLContext
spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .master('local') \
    .appName('muthootSample1') \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '28g') \
    .config('spark.driver.memory','4g')\
    .config("spark.cores.max", "6") \
    .getOrCreate()
```

Comment: None of the "changes" here are actually changes. The changes to the import lines are functionally the same as what you had before and the configuration you added in your edit are also identical to the values you suggest.