# Pyspark error: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I am using Pyspark to run some commands in Jupyter Notebook but it is throwing error. I tried solutions provided in this link ([Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po)) 
and I tried doing the solution provided here (such as Changing the path to C:Java, Uninstalling Java SDK 10 and reinstalling Java 8, still it is throwing me the same error.

I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pyspark, and I tried running from anaconda prompt as well still I am getting the same error. I am using Python 3.7 and pyspark version is 2.4.0.

If I use this code, I get this error."Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number".

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sc = SparkContext() 
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vector, Vectors
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover, Word2Vec
```

But If I remove sparkcontext from this code runs fine, but I would need spark context for my solution. Below code without spark context does not throw any error.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
from pyspark.mllib.linalg import Vector, Vectors
from nltk.stem.wordnet import WordNetLemmatizer
from pyspark.ml.feature import RegexTokenizer, StopWordsRemover, Word2Vec
```

I would appreciate if I could get any help figuring this out. I am using Windows 10 64 bit operating system.

Here is full error code picture.

[image]

Answer (score 9):

Type this in you bash terminal, and it will be fixed:

```sh
export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2] pyspark-shell"
```

All this does is export `pyspark-shell` to the shell environment variable `PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS`.

Comment: Thank You @Xilpex, is this for Windows or linux ? I am using Windows 64 bit

Comment: @Avi this is for Linux.

Comment: dude!!!  I went through about twenty resources and none worked until this. THANK YOU!

Comment: btw I have copied your answer to my question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/56916343/1056563

Comment: Thank you ! , Works for me as well

Comment: Thanks a ton! @xilpex It worked for me as well.

Comment: +1! Thanks for this! After seeing such a generic error I thought I'll have to spend a lot of time, but this did the trick! Thanks again! :)

Comment: This has not been working for me. Still getting `Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again` ... `RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number`. I am trying to run tests with `pytest-spark`

Answer (score 5):

Try This

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/java
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-installer
```

Worked for me using linux.It should work for windows too

this link will help you for coz you are an windows user https://superuser.com/questions/947220/how-to-install-packages-apt-get-install-in-windows

Answer (score 2):

Actually, this Error Occurs due to we are not setting JAVA_HOME in our environment
variable. I was also getting the same error but without setting JAVA_HOME  and SPARK_HOME you can set them in your Python code directly. But for that you should download JDK1.8, I am able to do it now. below is the solution with code -

```
import os
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:/Program Files/Java/jdk1.8.0_45"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = "C:/Users/Rahul/Downloads/spark-3.1.3-bin-hadoop2.7"
import findspark
findspark.init()
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
df=spark.read.options(delimiter=",", header=True).csv("C:/Users/Downloads/sample_movie.csv")
df.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve it.
open "edit the system variable" > "Environment Variables" > in "System Variables" (lower half part) > double click "PATH" > click "NEW" and add "C:\WINDOWS\System32" (without quotes).

Answer (score 0):

How did you install spark?? Clearly, you are having trouble starting a java process, which is what that error means.

You may want to install Spark again using the instructions to the letter, wherever you found them. However, you could also use `conda`, (anaconda or [miniconda](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)), in which case installing pyspark will also get a current java for you

```
conda install pyspark
```

Comment: btw: it is not surprising that the version without a context worked, you didn't actually try to launch anything yet.

Comment: I used pip install pyspark on my anaconda cmd prompt.

Comment: For Windows 10, I had to reset java_home to jdk1.8 from a recent upgrade of jdk 16 to resolve this issue..also ensure winutils is for hadoop 3.2.1 and pyspark 3.1.2

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue then I installed jdk 8 not into program files but in a new  separate folder called Java and issue got resolved.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
postgres_jar_path = "C:\Program Files\Java\lib\postgresql-42.7.1.jar"

spark = SparkSession.builder \
    .appName("ELtT") \
    .config("spark.jars", postgres_jar_path) \
    .getOrCreate()
```

I encountered the same error above because I did not specify the path to my jar file properly

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).