# How to Convert a Pandas Dataframe to a Spark Dataframe?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, apache-spark, pyspark

I downloaded and installed the Windows 64-bit driver from the link below.

https://www.databricks.com/spark/odbc-drivers-download

Then, I did `pip install pyspark`

Now, I am testing the code below, which seems very straightforward.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
import pandas as pd

# Assuming you already have a SparkSession created
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()

# Create a Pandas DataFrame
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({
    'column1': [1, 2, 3],
    'column2': ['A', 'B', 'C']
})

# Convert Pandas DataFrame to PySpark DataFrame
spark_df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)

# Show the PySpark DataFrame
spark_df.show()
```

When I run the code, I get this error message.

```
PySparkRuntimeError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 5
      2 import pandas as pd
      4 # Assuming you already have a SparkSession created
----> 5 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("example").getOrCreate()
      7 # Create a Pandas DataFrame
      8 pandas_df = pd.DataFrame({
      9     'column1': [1, 2, 3],
     10     'column2': ['A', 'B', 'C']
     11 })

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\sql\session.py:497, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    495     sparkConf.set(key, value)
    496 # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 497 sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    498 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    499 # by all sessions.
    500 session = SparkSession(sc, options=self._options)

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:515, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    513 with SparkContext._lock:
    514     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 515         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    516     assert SparkContext._active_spark_context is not None
    517     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:201, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls, udf_profiler_cls, memory_profiler_cls)
    195 if gateway is not None and gateway.gateway_parameters.auth_token is None:
    196     raise ValueError(
    197         "You are trying to pass an insecure Py4j gateway to Spark. This"
    198         " is not allowed as it is a security risk."
    199     )
--> 201 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    202 try:
    203     self._do_init(
    204         master,
    205         appName,
   (...)
    215         memory_profiler_cls,
    216     )

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:436, in SparkContext._ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    434 with SparkContext._lock:
    435     if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 436         SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    437         SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    439     if instance:

File ~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\java_gateway.py:107, in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    104     time.sleep(0.1)
    106 if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 107     raise PySparkRuntimeError(
    108         error_class="JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED",
    109         message_parameters={},
    110     )
    112 with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:
    113     gateway_port = read_int(info)

PySparkRuntimeError: [JAVA_GATEWAY_EXITED] Java gateway process exited before sending its port number.
```

What did I do wrong? What am I missing here?

Comment: What's your Java and Spark version?

Comment: Have you already consulted [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55292779/6394617)?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK this problem usually occurs when you don't set the `JAVA_HOME` environment variable or you set it incorrectly.

Please `echo $JAVA_HOME` on your terminal and see if the path is actually
the path to your Java installation.

If this isn't the case, you can set it by doing the following:

```py
import os
JAVA_HOME = /path/to/your/java/bin
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = JAVA_HOME
```

If this still doesn't work, you can try setting the env variable manually by typing this on the cmd.

```
setx JAVA_HOME <YOUR_JAVA_HOME_PATH>
```

Hope this will work!