# error while defining SparkContext in jupyter notebooke(Python 3 (ipykernel))

Tags: python, pyspark, jupyter-notebook, anaconda

[sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ouNha.png)

using anaconda`s Jupyter notebook, this is my first time using pyspark.
what I am trying to do is defining the spark environment to read a csv file on the local disk.

Edit: added the text as user2314737 asked for text instead of an image and now StackOverflow wants me to add more details as my text body Is mostly code XD so i have to chat with you all in this part you can ignore this text body, but i do have to write until i can press save edits.

Input:

```py
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PrdectiveModel")
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf) ----> the error is in this line
```

Output:

```py
Py4JJavaError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [13], in <cell line: 3>()
      1 from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
      2 conf = SparkConf().setAppName("PrdectiveModel")
----> 3 sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:146, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    144 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145 try:
--> 146     self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
    147                   conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    148 except:
    149     # If an error occurs, clean up in order to allow future SparkContext creation:
    150     self.stop()

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:209, in SparkContext._do_init(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, jsc, profiler_cls)
    206 self.environment["PYTHONHASHSEED"] = os.environ.get("PYTHONHASHSEED", "0")
    208 # Create the Java SparkContext through Py4J
--> 209 self._jsc = jsc or self._initialize_context(self._conf._jconf)
    210 # Reset the SparkConf to the one actually used by the SparkContext in JVM.
    211 self._conf = SparkConf(_jconf=self._jsc.sc().conf())

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pyspark\context.py:329, in SparkContext._initialize_context(self, jconf)
    325 def _initialize_context(self, jconf):
    326     """
    327     Initialize SparkContext in function to allow subclass specific initialization
    328     """
--> 329     return self._jvm.JavaSparkContext(jconf)

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\java_gateway.py:1585, in JavaClass.__call__(self, *args)
   1579 command = proto.CONSTRUCTOR_COMMAND_NAME +\
   1580     self._command_header +\
   1581     args_command +\
   1582     proto.END_COMMAND_PART
   1584 answer = self._gateway_client.send_command(command)
-> 1585 return_value = get_return_value(
   1586     answer, self._gateway_client, None, self._fqn)
   1588 for temp_arg in temp_args:
   1589     temp_arg._detach()

File E:\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\py4j\protocol.py:326, in get_return_value(answer, gateway_client, target_id, name)
    324 value = OUTPUT_CONVERTER[type](answer[2:], gateway_client)
    325 if answer[1] == REFERENCE_TYPE:
--> 326     raise Py4JJavaError(
    327         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}.\n".
    328         format(target_id, ".", name), value)
    329 else:
    330     raise Py4JError(
    331         "An error occurred while calling {0}{1}{2}. Trace:\n{3}\n".
    332         format(target_id, ".", name, value))

Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.<init>(BlockManagerMasterEndpoint.scala:110)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.$anonfun$create$9(SparkEnv.scala:348)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.registerOrLookupEndpoint$1(SparkEnv.scala:287)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:336)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:191)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:277)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:460)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

so I did as you have said checked the environment and such.
even used findsprak

input

```
import findspark

findspark.init()
findspark.find()
```

output

```
'C:\\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2'
```

so it is correctly installed and can be imported without any problems.

YET!!!!!!!!!!!!! my error still remains

```
sc = SparkContext(conf=conf)
```

why does this single line cause the error

..............

So I tried a different code

```
import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql("select 'spark' as hello ")

df.show()
```

and now a different error appears

```
iRuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [6], in <cell line: 5>()
      1 import pyspark
      3 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 5 spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
      7 df = spark.sql("select 'spark' as hello ")
      9 df.show()

File C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\sql\session.py:228, in SparkSession.Builder.getOrCreate(self)
    226         sparkConf.set(key, value)
    227     # This SparkContext may be an existing one.
--> 228     sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(sparkConf)
    229 # Do not update `SparkConf` for existing `SparkContext`, as it's shared
    230 # by all sessions.
    231 session = SparkSession(sc)

File C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py:392, in SparkContext.getOrCreate(cls, conf)
    390 with SparkContext._lock:
    391     if SparkContext._active_spark_context is None:
--> 392         SparkContext(conf=conf or SparkConf())
    393     return SparkContext._active_spark_context

File C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py:144, in SparkContext.__init__(self, master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer, conf, gateway, jsc, profiler_cls)
    139 if gateway is not None and gateway.gateway_parameters.auth_token is None:
    140     raise ValueError(
    141         "You are trying to pass an insecure Py4j gateway to Spark. This"
    142         " is not allowed as it is a security risk.")
--> 144 SparkContext._ensure_initialized(self, gateway=gateway, conf=conf)
    145 try:
    146     self._do_init(master, appName, sparkHome, pyFiles, environment, batchSize, serializer,
    147                   conf, jsc, profiler_cls)

File C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\context.py:339, in SparkContext._ensure_initialized(cls, instance, gateway, conf)
    337 with SparkContext._lock:
    338     if not SparkContext._gateway:
--> 339         SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway(conf)
    340         SparkContext._jvm = SparkContext._gateway.jvm
    342     if instance:

File C:\spark-3.2.1-bin-hadoop3.2\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py:108, in launch_gateway(conf, popen_kwargs)
    105     time.sleep(0.1)
    107 if not os.path.isfile(conn_info_file):
--> 108     raise RuntimeError("Java gateway process exited before sending its port number")
    110 with open(conn_info_file, "rb") as info:
    111     gateway_port = read_int(info)

RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

hope there is a relation to the two errors

Thanks for taking your time reading this, hope it gets solved

Comment: Please include code+errors (full stack trace) in your question as text and not as an image!

Comment: Please include code+errors (full stack trace) in your question as text and not as an image! – 
user2314737
done

Answer (score 0):

One common problem is a wrong Java version.

Check that Java 8 (or higher) is installed and that the JAVA_HOME environment variable is set (to the installation directory).

If this doesn't help, you might also need to set the variables SPARK_HOME and PYTHONPATH (see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/getting_started/install.html).

Comment: tired. 
made sure java is installed and the environment is correct still the same.

Comment: so i looked up a simple spark code
```
import pyspark

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()

df = spark.sql("select 'spark' as hello ")

df.show()
````
and it too gets an error

Comment: do you get the same errors in they pyspark shell? (just type `pyspark` at a command prompt). Inside the `pyspark` shell you should have `spark` already defined, so just start from `df = spark.sql("select 'spark' as hello ")`

Comment: See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032134/2314737

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same error
but it will resolved in following 2 steps.

1. install openjdk
2. Write the following code

   ```
    import pyspark
    from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

    #Create SparkSession
    spark = SparkSession.builder
                .master("local[1]")
                .appName("myapp.com")
                .getOrCreate()
   ```

Comment: the question is how to define a spark "context", not a spark "session"