# PySpark script is not getting completed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I have written PySpark script to read the data from database and csv, the script is not getting completed, it being executed. Below is the code,

```py
import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.context import SparkContext
import os

os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = 'path/to/java/bin/'

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("") \
.config("spark.jars", "path/to/postgresql-42.3.2.jar") \
.config("spark.driver.extraClassPath", "path/to/postgresql-42.3.2.jar") \
.config("spark.executor.extraClassPath", "path/to/postgresql-42.3.2.jar") \
.getOrCreate()


df_etl_control = spark.read \
    .format("jdbc") \
    .option("url", "jdbc:postgresql://database_connection") \
    .option("query", "select * from table") \
    .option("user", "wwwww") \
    .option("password", "wwwwww").load()

df = spark.read.option("header",True).csv("path/to/csv")
df.printSchema()
```

I was getting `RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number` error before adding java home path `os.environ['JAVA_HOME'] = 'path/to/java/bin/'*`. After adding the path, job is not getting completed.

Any suggestion would be great.

Comment: How are you running it? Jupyter? spark-submit?

Comment: Am running in Jupyter notebook

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po)