# How could I resolve Pyspark error on SparkSession?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, hdfs, bigdata

Please help me with resolving the problem I'm facing.

Here is the code which I run on a Jupyter notebook.

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
```

--> I got error as

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\MOHANA~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_18536/4172048100.py in <module>
      1 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
----> 2 spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('abc').getOrCreate()
    
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Comment: Could you show more about your error traceback and your Java version?

Comment: This might help: [Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po)