# Java gateway process exited before sending its port number error even after correctly configuring

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

Working with pyspark and have tried just about everything. I followed a lot of the advice in this stack over flow post [Pyspark: Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po) to no avail. I am sure that I have spark installed right. I followed this youtube video for the installation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cYL42BBL3Fo

I am using Spark 3.3.1 btw

Here is how I am defining the SparkSession

```
spark = SparkSession \
    .builder \
    .master('yarn') \
    .appName('ChainAnalysis_v0') \
    .config('spark.jars', 'gs://spark-lib/bigquery/spark-bigquery-latest.jar') \
    .config('spark.executor.cores', '3') \
    .config('spark.executor.memory', '5g') \
    .config("spark.sql.broadcastTimeout", "36000")\
    .getOrCreate()
```

Here are how my enviroment variables are configured

```
os.environ["JAVA_HOME"] = "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-11.0.16.1"
os.environ["SPARK_HOME"] = 'C:\\Spark'
os.environ["PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS"] = "--master local[3] pyspark-shell"
```

Even with all of this I am still running into the error

```
RuntimeError: Java gateway process exited before sending its port number
```

Any Suggestions?

Comment: Should I switch to Java8, I have already tried this by using jkd1.8 but still nothing

Comment: Side note, in your `SPARK_HOME` symbol, you need EITHER the `r` prefix or the double-slashes.  One or the other, not both.  Compare to the previous line.  What you have there will be seen as "C:\\Spark", which is not a valid path on Windows.

Comment: And did that solve the problem?  That could have been it.

Comment: No unfortunately not