# spark, delta-spark, python and java compatible version

Tags: pyspark, delta-lake

As recommended by [pyspark exception on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po) and [delta-lake & spark compatible version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31841509/pyspark-exception-java-gateway-process-exited-before-sending-the-driver-its-po), I have following versions installed in my mac locally:

- echo $PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS : --master local[3] pyspark-shell
- echo $JAVA_HOME : /opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/21.0.1/libexec/openjdk.jdk/Contents/Home
- python -V: Python 3.10.12
- pip list | grep delta-spark : 2.4.0
- pip list | grep pyspark : 3.4.1
- pip list | grep py4j : 0.10.9.7

I have setup virtualenvs where python, pyspark, delta-spark, py4j installed.

When I run pytest or invoke pyspark session locally in terminal of pycharm I get this error:
**py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.spark.unsafe.array.ByteArrayMethods**

I also referred to [spark 3.4.1 install](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/api/python/getting_started/install.html) which says below:

1. Python version supported: Python 3.7 and above.
2. py4j (required): 0.10.9.7
3. Note that PySpark requires Java 8 or later with JAVA_HOME properly set.

The versions all looks fine to me. Could you suggest what I am missing here.

Thank you

Comment: From spark 3.4.1 [docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.4.1/): *Spark runs on Java 8/11/17*

Comment: Thank you. Let me try downgrading my local java version to 17 and update here.

Comment: Referred https://medium.com/@manvendrapsingh/installing-many-jdk-versions-on-macos-dfc177bc8c2b and https://medium.com/notes-for-geeks/java-home-and-java-home-on-macos-f246cab643bd to point to jdk 17.

Problem resolved.