PySpark is running out of memory using Splink
I am using the splink library for user clustering. 
I am currently using DuckDB as my database, I read that SparkDB is more efficient and I wanted to try it. 
The problem is that I get an OutOfMemoryError, even tho I'm just using the code from the splink documentation. 
This is the code
from splink.spark.jar_location import similarity_jar_location

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import types

conf = SparkConf()

conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "12g")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "16")

path = similarity_jar_location()
conf.set("spark.jars", path)

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("./tmp_checkpoints")

I already get the error at: sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)
This is the link to the documentation:
https://moj-analytical-services.github.io/splink/demos/examples/spark/deduplicate_1k_synthetic.html
And this is a part of my error:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached

I was trying to cluster the users from the preexisting dataset in splink using the SparkDB as database. 
I was expecting everything to work like it did with DuckDB.
Edit: 
This is the complete log:
[108,932s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,932s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,932s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,932s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,932s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,932s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,933s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,939s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,939s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "rpc-boss-21-1"
[108,940s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,940s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "rpc-boss-21-2"
[108,940s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start thread "Unknown thread" - pthread_create failed (EAGAIN) for attributes: stacksize: 1024k, guardsize: 0k, detached.
[108,940s][warning][os,thread] Failed to start the native thread for java.lang.Thread "rpc-boss-21-3"
24/07/16 09:44:28 WARN SparkContext: Another SparkContext is being constructed (or threw an exception in its constructor). This may indicate an error, since only one SparkContext should be running in this JVM (see SPARK-2243). The other SparkContext was created at:
org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:75)
java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:53)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)
24/07/16 09:44:28 WARN AbstractChannel: Force-closing a channel whose registration task was not accepted by an event loop: [id: 0xb5021194]
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: unable to create native thread: possibly out of memory or process/resource limits reached
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start0(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.start(Thread.java:1526)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.ThreadPerTaskExecutor.execute(ThreadPerTaskExecutor.java:32)
    at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$1.execute(ThreadExecutorMap.java:57)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.doStartThread(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:986)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.startThread(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:955)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:838)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute0(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:827)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.execute(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:817)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register(AbstractChannel.java:483)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:89)
    at io.netty.channel.SingleThreadEventLoop.register(SingleThreadEventLoop.java:83)
    at io.netty.channel.MultithreadEventLoopGroup.register(MultithreadEventLoopGroup.java:86)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.initAndRegister(AbstractBootstrap.java:323)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.doBind(AbstractBootstrap.java:272)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.AbstractBootstrap.bind(AbstractBootstrap.java:268)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.init(TransportServer.java:149)
    at org.apache.spark.network.server.TransportServer.<init>(TransportServer.java:84)
    at org.apache.spark.network.TransportContext.createServer(TransportContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv.startServer(NettyRpcEnv.scala:125)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.$anonfun$create$1(NettyRpcEnv.scala:495)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.$anonfun$create$1$adapted(NettyRpcEnv.scala:494)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.$anonfun$startServiceOnPort$2(Utils.scala:2256)
    at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach$mVc$sp(Range.scala:158)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.startServiceOnPort(Utils.scala:2248)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnvFactory.create(NettyRpcEnv.scala:499)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcEnv$.create(RpcEnv.scala:58)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:276)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createDriverEnv(SparkEnv.scala:196)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.createSparkEnv(SparkContext.scala:284)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:483)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:75)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:53)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:502)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:486)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:374)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:238)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.waitForCommands(ClientServerConnection.java:182)
    at py4j.ClientServerConnection.run(ClientServerConnection.java:106)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1583)



Does the machine and/or VM you're running on have less than 12 GIB of free memory?

Sorry, I forgot to mention that. I am running it on my laptop which has 32 GB of memory but increasing the memory in the settings does not help and decreasing the parallelism does not help neither. Thanks for the reply!

What is the max memory your laptop is usings when you run this? Also which spark version are you using? - The splink handling for spark 3 looks like it was added about 10 months ago. If you installed splink over 10 months ago and are using spark 3+ this could possibly cause issues.
https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink/blob/master/splink/spark/jar_location.py#L19

I installed splink and spark just last week. My splink version is: 3.9.15 and my spark version is 3.5.1. I'll try it again using spark 2 maybe. Thanks for the help! About the memory I don't really know because it just gives me an error in like 0.1 seconds.

I might have found the solution. 
I used this post as reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51032134/14287484 

The main problem is that I had to install JDK 8 for my code to work. 
JDK 21 did not work. 
The Following instructions are meant for Ubuntu systems.
Install JDK 8
Step 1
Install JDK 8
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install openjdk-8-jdk-headless -qq

Step 2
Update the java alternatives
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/java java /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/java 2
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/javac javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac 2

Step 3
Select the number corresponding the JDK 8 version
sudo update-alternatives --config java
sudo update-alternatives --config javac

Step 4
Check your JDK version
java -version
Add JDK 8 to JAVA_HOME
I will only focus for the current user profile (not system wide).
Edit the .basrc file
nano ~/.bashrc

Add the following lines at the bottom by
setting the JAVA_HOME and updating the PATH.
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

Apply the changes
source ~/.bashrc

Check if the changes were successful
java -version

At last
I did reboot my system, but I can't say for certain if it's necessary. 
Running following code now worked.
from splink.spark.jar_location import similarity_jar_location

from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql import types

conf = SparkConf()

conf.set("spark.driver.memory", "6g")
conf.set("spark.default.parallelism", "16")


# Add custom similarity functions, which are bundled with Splink
# documented here: https://github.com/moj-analytical-services/splink_scalaudfs
path = similarity_jar_location()
conf.set("spark.jars", path)

sc = SparkContext.getOrCreate(conf=conf)

spark = SparkSession(sc)
spark.sparkContext.setCheckpointDir("./tmp_checkpoints")

import warnings
spark.sparkContext.setLogLevel("ERROR")
warnings.simplefilter("ignore", UserWarning)


from splink.datasets import splink_datasets
pandas_df = splink_datasets.fake_1000

df = spark.createDataFrame(pandas_df)


If you have any questions, feel free to comment or edit this post.
