# PySpark - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

Hy,

I have been run Spark multiple times (Spyder IDE).
Today I got this error (the code it's the same)

```
from py4j.java_gateway import JavaGateway
gateway = JavaGateway()

os.environ['SPARK_HOME']="C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0"
os.environ['JAVA_HOME']="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_71"
sys.path.append("C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0/python/")
os.environ['HADOOP_HOME']="C:/Apache/spark-1.6.0/winutils/"

from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark import SparkConf

conf = SparkConf()
    The system cannot find the path specified.
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Apache\spark-1.6.0\python\pyspark\conf.py", line 104, in __init__
        SparkContext._ensure_initialized()
      File "C:\Apache\spark-1.6.0\python\pyspark\context.py", line 245, in _ensure_initialized
        SparkContext._gateway = gateway or launch_gateway()
      File "C:\Apache\spark-1.6.0\python\pyspark\java_gateway.py", line 94, in launch_gateway
        raise Exception("Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number")
    Exception: Java gateway process exited before sending the driver its port number
```

What's go wrong? 
thanks for your time.

Comment: I think you should follow the answer mentioned at this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763951/spark-context-sc-not-defined/30851037#30851037

Comment: Ok... Someone install a new java version in VirtualMachine. I'm only change this os.environ['JAVA_HOME']="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91" and works again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok... Someone install a new java version in VirtualMachine. I'm only change this

```
os.environ['JAVA_HOME']="C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_91"
```

and works again.
thks for your time.