# I can not run scala from Jupyter

Tags: scala, apache-spark, jupyter, apache-spark-mllib

I'm in jupyter, I select kernel scala 2.11, when I place
`data val = matrix (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`
runs smoothly when returning data: `Array [Int] = Array (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`

then when I execute
`val distData = sc.parallelize (data)`
It returns

```
 File "<ipython-input-2-a082d435698a>", line 1
    val distData = sc.parallelize(data)
               ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

[image: imagen con error]

Comment: This usually happens when the error is on the previous line, something like a missing parenthesis or something. Can you please run everything in order or in one cell so we can see the actual order of operations? Also, it looks like you don't have a valid spark context either from the output of your third cell, which will be your next issue.

Comment: @kdq0 Adjunt image 2 with code in one line

Answer (score 0):

@kdq0 Adjunt image 2 with code in one line

[Adjunt image 2 with code in one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvUDN.jpg)

Comment: Okay, it looks like once you made the execution simple and in the right order, it moved you to your next error, which is like I said, you don't have a valid spark context. There are many reasons this could be and many of those reasons have been answered already, so spend some time digging around for already posted solutions. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30763951/spark-context-sc-not-defined) are a ton of possible reasons.

Comment: Also, just a tip, you should have added this to the original question instead of making it an answer.